# Would trailers for canon material be considered canon?

Tags: discussion, canon

As an example to illustrate me question consider this:

A mid-season trailer for season 2 of Star Wars Rebels was released recently and contains some pretty interesting things such as

> a green crossguard lightsaber and 2 white lightsabers.

So seeing how Rebels is main canon, can the trailer be considered canon as well?

Or more generally, are trailers containing impending canon content to be considered canon?

Or is it inappropriate to cite trailers as evidence on this site?

Comment: I'd say they're canonical enough to be worth citing in an answer, but maybe a lower level of canon, especially since sometimes scenes appear *only* in a trailer and not in the film itself. But I'm more of a novels guy than films and TV, so others will probably be able to give you a surer answer.

Comment: The other problem with trailers is the lack of context. As a quick example: the trailers for The Force Awakens contain only scenes which are in the actual movie but out of context seem to strongly imply that X will be a Jedi, but when you go watch the movie you discover that actually Y will be a Jedi. So if anyone had used that in an answer before the movie came out, they'd be a bit screwed now. But I still think it's fine to cite trailers for things that currently have no canon answer elsewhere; just be prepared to update your answer when the real thing comes out.

Answer (score 3):

### Star Wars trailers are not canon (in themselves).

Trailers are usually treated in the same way as any other mixed-canon source (such as a novelisation or pre-2014 factbook). The material in the trailer that appears in the show is canon. The material that appears in the trailer that doesn't appear in the show is non-canon and is treated as a "deleted scene".

That being said, you absolutely can quote them as evidence in your answers. Non-canon answers and deleted scenes are often an excellent way to understand how the makers were thinking, even if the actual material ended up on the cutting-room floor.

Comment: Good point about the deleted scenes.

Answer (score 1):

**Trailer material is canon, with caveats.**

It’s part of the published material from the same people who make the film and/or TV show, so I think it qualifies as canon. However, I’d class it as a lower level of canon: in particular, if the film or episode is released and contradicts the trailer, then the full version takes precedence.

You have to be a little carful: trailers don’t have context, they and be designed to be misleading, and sometimes they include material omitted from the final film.

I think it’s fine to use a trailer as source material, particularly if we don’t have anything else to go on. Just be ready to update your answer if the film is released and it’s different to what we saw in the trailer.